# Drupal::httpClient() and proxy settings

Tags: http-request

I've defined a proxy in my settings.php:

```
$settings['http_client_config']['proxy']['http'] = 'http://ip:port';
$settings['http_client_config']['proxy']['https'] = 'http://ip:port';
$settings['http_client_config']['proxy']['no'] = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost'];
```

In real I've replaced ip and port with nummeric values.

In a custom module I've defined:

```
$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
//$request = $client->get($this->source_url.'service=wms&request=getcapabilities');
```

These works, when Im not behind a proxy. How, can I add the proxy settings to this request?

```
$set =\Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get('http_client_config');
$proxy = $set['proxy'];
//Get GetCapabilies.
$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
$request = $client->get($this->source_url.'service=wms&request=getcapabilities');
```

I don't find any way to add the proxy settings.

Comment: `$client` is a Guzzle client, so you can use its standard methods: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#proxy

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all http client config to the "client factory". You can also include your own custom settings.

```
$settings = \Drupal::service('settings');
$clientConfig = $settings->get('http_client_config') ?? [];
$client = \Drupal::service('http_client_factory')
                   ->fromOptions($clientConfig);
```